# Static header and footer while page reload and navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I want to create a site in which the header and footer remains as it it while navigating to other pages and only the content area got changed and URL. The sample website is http://www.tamarindsq.com/. But I couldn't find the solution, i tried to see the source code of it. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "remains as it is" ? I think you just mean that it doesn't seem to reload...but that would just be HTML/CSS/JS load optimization :)

Comment: The menu reloads just like everything else, but appears to remain while the rest of the content loads purely because the content is bulkier. On a slow connection, the menu would lag with the rest of the content.

Comment: @Timmah No, it wouldn't. as an answer to your question, look into Ajax and jQuery to load the content only and try to enable caching on your website, so all the elements would only be loaded once

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".menu_one").click(function(){
  $("#content").load("menu_one_content.html");
});
```

Look into JQuery `load()`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with Iframe I think If you don't want your header footer to refreshed and only your content area changed.

Create page where your header and footer area will be same and in content area you need to place iframe.

Now based on menu click you can change source of IFrame from JavaScript like following.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1177572.aspx?is+it+possible+to+change+iframe+src+using+javascript+